# How can I preserve colnames through `apply` and `lapply` operations?

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, names, lapply

I have a data.frame called RawHM and want, for each row, to evaluate sets of columns defined by the entries in the list AllList, in order to see if there is enough non-NA observations (not less than 2) to keep the column set of entries for that row. If not, the column set entries should be substituted with NA's.

AllList:

```
> dput(AllList)
structure(list(EGI = c("OO", "PP", "QQ"), Ref = c("RR", "SS", 
"TT")), .Names = c("EGI", "Ref"))
```

RawHM:

```
> dput(head(RawHM,10))
structure(list(OO = c(2.26128283268031, NA, NA, NA, 3.1189673217816, 
2.68131772865193, 1.50542478607416, NA, NA, NA), PP = c(NA, 2.86537733048028, 
2.02969026818987, NA, 2.54112005565494, 3.01623803266379, 1.73909499803785, 
2.49712237003491, NA, 1.67635525591635), QQ = c(NA, NA, 1.91968060122123, 
NA, NA, 2.63463138625395, NA, NA, NA, NA), RR = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1.01488582084669, 1.01944283768403, NA, 1.06329113924051, 
NA), SS = c(0.950310559006211, 0.924124326404927, 1.07886334610473, 
0.951793999929161, 0.847931452310888, 0.879173290937997, 0.882126364182319, 
NA, NA, 0.713085668766746), TT = c(NA, NA, 1.09812749411644, 
NA, 0.9994646420402, 1.21090641120118, 1.25090285854196, NA, 
NA, NA)), .Names = c("OO", "PP", "QQ", "RR", "SS", "TT"), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 15L, 16L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 30L, 36L, 40L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have tried by making a function:

```
func<-function(x)unlist(lapply(AllList,function(y)if(length(na.omit(x[unlist(y)]))<2){rep(NA,length(unlist(y)))} else{x[unlist(y)]}))
```

And then:

```
output<-t(apply(RawHM,1,func))
```

Which works in priciple but doesnt preserve the colnames, which i want to be the same as in the RawHM dataframe. I would prefer to avoid renaming the columns afterwards..

```
> dput(head(output,10))
structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.1189673217816, 2.68131772865193, 
1.50542478607416, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.02969026818987, NA, 2.54112005565494, 
3.01623803266379, 1.73909499803785, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.91968060122123, 
NA, NA, 2.63463138625395, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1.01488582084669, 1.01944283768403, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.07886334610473, 
NA, 0.847931452310888, 0.879173290937997, 0.882126364182319, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.09812749411644, NA, 0.9994646420402, 1.21090641120118, 
1.25090285854196, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(10L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "15", "16", "23", "24", "25", "30", "36", "40"
    ), NULL))
```

Any help would be very welcome :-)
Regards
Mads

Answer (score 0):

`func` is a very strange function... funky even!

When you use `apply` your data gets converted to a matrix from a data.frame. Your function seems to operate differently if it is a data.frame rather than a matrix:

```
func(RawHM[1,])
   EGI.OO    EGI.PP    EGI.QQ    Ref.RR    Ref.SS    Ref.TT 
2.2612828        NA        NA        NA 0.9503106        NA 
func(as.matrix(RawHM)[1,])
EGI1 EGI2 EGI3 Ref1 Ref2 Ref3 
  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Note that you get different results, and different names!

In any case, the names issue arises from the fact that when you produce the NAs, there are no names, so the result give inconsistent output for `apply`. To fix this, here is a modification:

```
func2 <- function(x)unlist(lapply(AllList,function(y)if(length(na.omit(x[unlist(y)]))<2){sapply(y,function(z) NA)} else{x[unlist(y)]}))

t(apply(RawHM,1,func2))
     EGI.OO   EGI.PP   EGI.QQ   Ref.RR    Ref.SS    Ref.TT
1        NA       NA       NA       NA        NA        NA
2        NA       NA       NA       NA        NA        NA
15       NA 2.029690 1.919681       NA 1.0788633 1.0981275
16       NA       NA       NA       NA        NA        NA
23 3.118967 2.541120       NA       NA 0.8479315 0.9994646
24 2.681318 3.016238 2.634631 1.014886 0.8791733 1.2109064
25 1.505425 1.739095       NA 1.019443 0.8821264 1.2509029
30       NA       NA       NA       NA        NA        NA
36       NA       NA       NA       NA        NA        NA
40       NA       NA       NA       NA        NA        NA
```

Comment: Hi James...thx for your answer. However i would prefer a solution that gave me the exact same colnames as in RawHM (i.e. OO,PP,QQ, etc..) and not the compound name of the list name and the list member names...

Comment: @user2938867 Use `names(allList)<-NULL`